# Find all integer values that make two expressions coincide

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $n_x, n_y, p_x$ and $p_y$ be 4 integer values such that $p_x, p_y > 0$.

I want to find all integer values $k_x, k_y$ such that the following holds:

$$n_x + k_x p_x = n_y + k_y p_y$$

**My idea so far:**

We start by finding initial integer values of $k_x$ and $k_y$ that make the previous condition valid:

We rewrite the previous expression as:

$$k_x p_x - k_y p_y = n_y - n_x$$

Now, let $c_x, c_y$ be integer values such that
$c_x p_x + c_y p_y = GCD(p_x, p_y)$. These values exist and can be found due to the extended Euclidean Algorithm.

We multiply by a convenient representation of 1 to obtain:

$$\left(\frac{n_y - n_x}{GCD(p_x, p_y)}\right) c_x p_x + \left(\frac{n_y - n_x}{GCD(p_x, p_y)} \right) c_y p_y = n_y - n_x$$

And if $n_y - n_x$ is disible by $GCD(p_x, p_y)$ then we can find initial integer solutions

$$k_{x}^{0} = \left(\frac{n_y - n_x}{GCD(p_x, p_y)}\right) c_x$$
$$k_{y}^{0} = -\left(\frac{n_y - n_x}{GCD(p_x, p_y)}\right) c_y$$

This gives us an initial solution. I believe that all solutions to this problem are of the form:

$$k_x = k_{x}^{0} + n F_x$$
$$k_y = k_{y}^{0} + n F_y$$

for coefficients $F_x, F_y > 0$ , and $n$ ranging over the integers.

Is this correct? How can I find these coefficients $F_x, F_y$?

Addendum: I'm particularly interested in finding the minimal positive value that $N = n_x + k_x p_x$ can take.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Hi lesserfish. It would be a better notation that you take $a,p,b,q, x,y$ and post the equation
$$a+px=b+qy\iff px-qy=b-a$$ whose general solution comes from a particular solution $(x_0,y_0)$ so you have $$px-qy=b-a\\px_0-qy_0=b-a$$ so you have
$$p(x-x_0)-q(y-y_0)=0$$ so if $x=qn+x_0$ and $y=pn-y_0$ you get the trivial equality $pqn=qpn$ in other words your general solution is given by $$(x,y)=(qn+x_0,pn+y_0)$$

Comment: I agree with Piquito. You should choose a better notation. I would avoid subindices, but if you really want to use them to make enfasis in some symmetries, at least use $1$ and $2$ instead of $x$ and $y$ ($n_x$ should be used to indicate a dependence of $n$ on some variable $x$, but that's not how you are using it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your notation could be improved (see Piquito's comment), but let us keep it.

I agree with your method to find a particular solution $(k_x^0,k_y^0)$.

Then, your problem is equivalent to
$$p_x(k_x-k_x^0)=p_y(k_y-k_y^0)$$
i.e.
$$F_y(k_x-k_x^0)=F_x(k_y-k_y^0)$$
where

$F_x=\frac{p_y}{GCD(p_x,p_y)}$ and $F_y=\frac{p_x}{GCD(p_x,p_y)}$ are coprime.

Hence the solutions are of the form you wrote: for some integer $n$,
$$k_x=k_x^0+nF_x,\quad k_y=k_y^0+nF_y$$